# Constraints on a Vertical Stack View with 3 Images

Tags: autolayout, constraints

I have just started coding so forgive me if this is a very simple question but when I try to autolayout my stack view, I can't seem to get everything in the screen?  When I change the top and bottom, 1 of the images gets truncated:

[image: picture of truncated images in stack view]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure your Stack View properties are set to:

[image]

(with whatever vertical spacing you want)

Then constrain all 4 sides of the Stack View to the view (best to always respect the safe area):

[image]